# Java: fileoutputstream (access denied )

Tags: java, java-io, fileoutputstream

I am using AESCrypt open source library to encrypt file. This is my code

```
String password="asdfgh";
String frompath=new String("C:/Users/sabertooth/Desktop/error/pnberror.png");
String topath=new String("C:/Users/sabertooth/desktop/error/");
AESCrypt aes=new AESCrypt(false,password);
aes.encrypt(2, frompath, topath);
```

I am geeting access denied exception. Here is the stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sabertooth\desktop\error (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at AESCrypt.encrypt(AESCrypt.java:284)
    at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:28)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Posting the code for aescrypt.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2008 Vócali Sistemas Inteligentes
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * This class provides methods to encrypt and decrypt files using
 * <a href="http://www.aescrypt.com/aes_file_format.html">aescrypt file format</a>,
 * version 1 or 2.
 * <p>
 * Requires Java 6 and <a href="http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp">Java
 * Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files</a>.
 * <p>
 * Thread-safety and sharing: this class is not thread-safe.<br>
 * <tt>AESCrypt</tt> objects can be used as Commands (create, use once and dispose),
 * or reused to perform multiple operations (not concurrently though).
 *
 * @author Vócali Sistemas Inteligentes
 */
public class AESCrypt {
    private static final String JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "Please make sure "
        + "\"Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files\" "
        + "(http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) is installed on your JRE.";
    private static final String RANDOM_ALG = "SHA1PRNG";
    private static final String DIGEST_ALG = "SHA-256";
    private static final String HMAC_ALG = "HmacSHA256";
    private static final String CRYPT_ALG = "AES";
    private static final String CRYPT_TRANS = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
    private static final byte[] DEFAULT_MAC =
        {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0xef};
    private static final int KEY_SIZE = 32;
    private static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 16;
    private static final int SHA_SIZE = 32;

    private final boolean DEBUG;
    private byte[] password;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private Mac hmac;
    private SecureRandom random;
    private MessageDigest digest;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec1;
    private SecretKeySpec aesKey1;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec2;
    private SecretKeySpec aesKey2;


    /*******************
     * PRIVATE METHODS *
     *******************/


    /**
     * Prints a debug message on standard output if DEBUG mode is turned on.
     */
    protected void debug(String message) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("[DEBUG] " + message);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Prints a debug message on standard output if DEBUG mode is turned on.
     */
    protected void debug(String message, byte[] bytes) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("[DEBUG] ");
            buffer.append(message);
            buffer.append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                buffer.append(bytes[i]);
                buffer.append(i < bytes.length - 1 ? ", " : "]");
            }
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Generates a pseudo-random byte array.
     * @return pseudo-random byte array of <tt>len</tt> bytes.
     */
    protected byte[] generateRandomBytes(int len) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }


    /**
     * SHA256 digest over given byte array and random bytes.<br>
     * <tt>bytes.length</tt> * <tt>num</tt> random bytes are added to the digest.
     * <p>
     * The generated hash is saved back to the original byte array.<br>
     * Maximum array size is {@link #SHA_SIZE} bytes.
     */
    protected void digestRandomBytes(byte[] bytes, int num) {
        assert bytes.length <= SHA_SIZE;

        digest.reset();
        digest.update(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            random.nextBytes(bytes);
            digest.update(bytes);
        }
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }


    /**
     * Generates a pseudo-random IV based on time and this computer's MAC.
     * <p>
     * This IV is used to crypt IV 2 and AES key 2 in the file.
     * @return IV.
     */
    protected byte[] generateIv1() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] mac = null;
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (mac == null && ifaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                mac = ifaces.nextElement().getHardwareAddress();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore.
        }
        if (mac == null) {
            mac = DEFAULT_MAC;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            iv[i] = (byte) (time >> (i * 8));
        }
        System.arraycopy(mac, 0, iv, 8, mac.length);
        digestRandomBytes(iv, 256);
        return iv;
    }


    /**
     * Generates an AES key starting with an IV and applying the supplied user password.
     * <p>
     * This AES key is used to crypt IV 2 and AES key 2.
     * @return AES key of {@link #KEY_SIZE} bytes.
     */
    protected byte[] generateAESKey1(byte[] iv, byte[] password) {
        byte[] aesKey = new byte[KEY_SIZE];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, aesKey, 0, iv.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
            digest.reset();
            digest.update(aesKey);
            digest.update(password);
            aesKey = digest.digest();
        }
        return aesKey;
    }


    /**
     * Generates the random IV used to crypt file contents.
     * @return IV 2.
     */
    protected byte[] generateIV2() {
        byte[] iv = generateRandomBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
        digestRandomBytes(iv, 256);
        return iv;
    }


    /**
     * Generates the random AES key used to crypt file contents.
     * @return AES key of {@link #KEY_SIZE} bytes.
     */
    protected byte[] generateAESKey2() {
        byte[] aesKey = generateRandomBytes(KEY_SIZE);
        digestRandomBytes(aesKey, 32);
        return aesKey;
    }


    /**
     * Utility method to read bytes from a stream until the given array is fully filled.
     * @throws IOException if the array can't be filled.
     */
    protected void readBytes(InputStream in, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        if (in.read(bytes) != bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected end of file");
        }
    }


    /**************
     * PUBLIC API *
     **************/


    /**
     * Builds an object to encrypt or decrypt files with the given password.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if UTF-16 encoding is not supported.
     */
    public AESCrypt(String password) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this(false, password);
    }


    /**
     * Builds an object to encrypt or decrypt files with the given password.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if UTF-16 encoding is not supported.
     */
    public AESCrypt(boolean debug, String password) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            DEBUG = debug;
            setPassword(password);
            random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALG);
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(DIGEST_ALG);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CRYPT_TRANS);
            hmac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_ALG);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Changes the password this object uses to encrypt and decrypt.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if UTF-16 encoding is not supported.
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this.password = password.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        debug("Using password: ", this.password);
    }


    /**
     * The file at <tt>fromPath</tt> is encrypted and saved at <tt>toPath</tt> location.
     * <p>
     * <tt>version</tt> can be either 1 or 2.
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void encrypt(int version, String fromPath, String toPath)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromPath));
            debug("Opened for reading: " + fromPath);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));
            debug("Opened for writing: " + toPath);

            encrypt(version, in, out);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }           
        }
    }

    /**
     * The input stream is encrypted and saved to the output stream.
     * <p>
     * <tt>version</tt> can be either 1 or 2.<br>
     * None of the streams are closed.
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void encrypt(int version, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            byte[] text = null;

            ivSpec1 = new IvParameterSpec(generateIv1());
            aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey1(ivSpec1.getIV(), password), CRYPT_ALG);
            ivSpec2 = new IvParameterSpec(generateIV2());
            aesKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey2(), CRYPT_ALG);
            debug("IV1: ", ivSpec1.getIV());
            debug("AES1: ", aesKey1.getEncoded());
            debug("IV2: ", ivSpec2.getIV());
            debug("AES2: ", aesKey2.getEncoded());

            out.write("AES".getBytes("UTF-8")); // Heading.
            out.write(version); // Version.
            out.write(0);   // Reserved.
            if (version == 2) { // No extensions.
                out.write(0);
                out.write(0);
            }
            out.write(ivSpec1.getIV()); // Initialization Vector.

            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE];
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, ivSpec1);
            cipher.update(ivSpec2.getIV(), 0, BLOCK_SIZE, text);
            cipher.doFinal(aesKey2.getEncoded(), 0, KEY_SIZE, text, BLOCK_SIZE);
            out.write(text);    // Crypted IV and key.
            debug("IV2 + AES2 ciphertext: ", text);

            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey1.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            text = hmac.doFinal(text);
            out.write(text);    // HMAC from previous cyphertext.
            debug("HMAC1: ", text);

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey2, ivSpec2);
            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey2.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            int len, last = 0;
            while ((len = in.read(text)) > 0) {
                cipher.update(text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE, text);
                hmac.update(text);
                out.write(text);    // Crypted file data block.
                last = len;
            }
            last &= 0x0f;
            out.write(last);    // Last block size mod 16.
            debug("Last block size mod 16: " + last);

            text = hmac.doFinal();
            out.write(text);    // HMAC from previous cyphertext.
            debug("HMAC2: ", text);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * The file at <tt>fromPath</tt> is decrypted and saved at <tt>toPath</tt> location.
     * <p>
     * The input file can be encrypted using version 1 or 2 of aescrypt.<br>
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void decrypt(String fromPath, String toPath)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromPath));
            debug("Opened for reading: " + fromPath);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));
            debug("Opened for writing: " + toPath);

            decrypt(new File(fromPath).length(), in, out);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }   


    /**
     * The input stream is decrypted and saved to the output stream.
     * <p>
     * The input file size is needed in advance.<br>
     * The input stream can be encrypted using version 1 or 2 of aescrypt.<br>
     * None of the streams are closed.
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void decrypt(long inSize, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            byte[] text = null, backup = null;
            long total = 3 + 1 + 1 + BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE + SHA_SIZE + 1 + SHA_SIZE;
            int version;

            text = new byte[3];
            readBytes(in, text);    // Heading.
            if (!new String(text, "UTF-8").equals("AES")) {
                throw new IOException("Invalid file header");
            }

            version = in.read();    // Version.
            if (version < 1 || version > 2) {
                throw new IOException("Unsupported version number: " + version);
            }
            debug("Version: " + version);

            in.read();  // Reserved.

            if (version == 2) { // Extensions.
                text = new byte[2];
                int len;
                do {
                    readBytes(in, text);
                    len = ((0xff & (int) text[0]) << 8) | (0xff & (int) text[1]);
                    if (in.skip(len) != len) {
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected end of extension");
                    }
                    total += 2 + len;
                    debug("Skipped extension sized: " + len);
                } while (len != 0);
            }

            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, text);    // Initialization Vector.
            ivSpec1 = new IvParameterSpec(text);
            aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey1(ivSpec1.getIV(), password), CRYPT_ALG);
            debug("IV1: ", ivSpec1.getIV());
            debug("AES1: ", aesKey1.getEncoded());

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, ivSpec1);
            backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, backup);  // IV and key to decrypt file contents.
            debug("IV2 + AES2 ciphertext: ", backup);
            text = cipher.doFinal(backup);
            ivSpec2 = new IvParameterSpec(text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
            aesKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(text, BLOCK_SIZE, KEY_SIZE, CRYPT_ALG);
            debug("IV2: ", ivSpec2.getIV());
            debug("AES2: ", aesKey2.getEncoded());

            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey1.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            backup = hmac.doFinal(backup);
            text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, text);    // HMAC and authenticity test.
            if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
                throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
            }
            debug("HMAC1: ", text);

            total = inSize - total; // Payload size.
            if (total % BLOCK_SIZE != 0) {
                throw new IOException("Input file is corrupt");
            }
            if (total == 0) {   // Hack: empty files won't enter block-processing for-loop below. 
                in.read();  // Skip last block size mod 16.
            }
            debug("Payload size: " + total);

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey2, ivSpec2);
            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey2.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            for (int block = (int) (total / BLOCK_SIZE); block > 0; block--) {
                int len = BLOCK_SIZE;
                if (in.read(backup, 0, len) != len) {   // Cyphertext block.
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected end of file contents");
                }
                cipher.update(backup, 0, len, text);
                hmac.update(backup, 0, len);
                if (block == 1) {
                    int last = in.read();   // Last block size mod 16.
                    debug("Last block size mod 16: " + last);
                    len = (last > 0 ? last : BLOCK_SIZE);
                }
                out.write(text, 0, len);
            }
            out.write(cipher.doFinal());

            backup = hmac.doFinal();
            text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, text);    // HMAC and authenticity test.
            if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
                throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
            }
            debug("HMAC2: ", text);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }


/*  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 4) {
                System.out.println("AESCrypt e|d password fromPath toPath");
                return;
            }
            AESCrypt aes = new AESCrypt(true, args[1]);
            switch (args[0].charAt(0)) {
            case 'e':
                aes.encrypt(2, args[2], args[3]);
                break;
            case 'd':
                aes.decrypt(args[2], args[3]);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid operation: must be (e)ncrypt or (d)ecrypt.");
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
*/        
}
```

There is a method encrypt which takes 3 arguments version frompath topath

Comment: don't know this lib but i would suspect it trying to write to a directory and therefor the error, try `String topath=new String("C:/Users/sabertooth/desktop/error/pnberror_encrypted.png");`

Comment: [AESCrypt](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/crypto/provider/AESCrypt.html) doesn't have encrypt method. Is it your own AESCrypt class?

Comment: Post the code of your AESCrypt class

Comment: Edited: posted the code for aescrypt class

Comment: You shouldn't post copyright code here.

Answer (score 6):

You can't write to a folder. And `C:/Users/sabertooth/desktop/error/` is a folder path.

Also, `new String("...")` is unnecessary. Just use `"..."`.

Comment: How do you know the encrypt method expect a file, not a folder? It's a custom one, the stack shows no package information, it's not the AESCrypt class from the lib.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that a FileOutputStream is trying to write to C:\Users\sabertooth\desktop\error.

Comment: Yes, but the path used in `FileOutputStream` may be built from the path + the file part of `frompath`. Are you sure writing to a folder cause an access denied?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I just tested it.